# MS Access 2010 Linking count results to individual records

Tags: sql, count, ms-access-2010

I have written a sql query in ms access 2010 which counts monthly enquiries, with the user inputting the month parameter.  It returns 2 columns - the month name and the total monthly enquiries for that month.

```
SELECT Format([DateOfEnquiry],"mmmm") AS [Month], Count(T_Enquiry.[DateOfEnquiry]) AS TotalMonthlyEnquiries
FROM T_Enquiry
GROUP BY Format([DateOfEnquiry],"mmmm")
HAVING (((Format([DateOfEnquiry],"mmmm"))=[Enter full name of month]));
```

After running this query, is it then possible to click on the value in the `TotalMonthlyEnquiries` column and have Access run another query which returns the individual records corresponding to that value (fields like `FamilyName`, `FirstName`, `Email`, `Phone`, `DateOfEnquiry` from `T_Enquiry`)?  If it is possible, how would this be achieved in ms access 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this in 2007 but should be very similar if not the same.  Create a query with as yours above (Query1 in this example).  Create another query which grabs the detail data you want from T_Enquiry (FamilyName, FirstName, Email, Phone, DateOfEnquiry) as Query2.

Create a datasheet form based on Query1 (I've called it frmQuery1 in this example) - I just used the form wizard to save time.  Open the form for editing and right-click on the TotalMonthlyEnquiries textbox and go to Properities.  On the Format tab, set DisplayAsHyperlink to Always (this will indicate to the user they can click on the link.  On the OnClick even on the textbox, enter the following code:

```
Private Sub TotalMonthlyEnquiries_Click()

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmQuery2", acFormDS

    Forms!frmQuery2.Filter = "Format([DateOfEnquiry], ""mmmm"") = '" & Me![Month] & "'"
    Forms!frmQuery2.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Save frmQuery1.  Create another wizard-based datasheet form off Query2 (the detail data) and save it as frmQuery2.

Now open frmQuery1 - you will be asked to supply a month.  When you do and the datasheet comes up, the quanity should be hyperlinked.  Click on the hyperlink and frmQuery2 should open up with the data for only the month in question.

Just a simple opening up of another form and passing the value (in this case, month name) from the first form to the second as the filter parameter.  There are more complex ways to do this, but this is one of the simplest.  Good luck.

Comment: Works perfectly in Access 2010.  This was quite a simple procedure.  I now have other possible uses for this technique throughout my database.

Comment: Glad it meets your needs.  If so, please mark as answer so that if another person comes they know it worked and can implement!

Comment: In the course of testing procedures with this technique, I have encountered the following:  1. When clicking on the hyperlinked name in the FamilyName field, Access 2010 prompts user to 'Enter Parameter Value'. 2. If 'OK' is clicked or a parameter is entered the code performs properly. 3. If 'Cancel' is clicked, MS Visual Basic returns an error msg 'Run-time error 2501. The OpenForm action was canceled'  Should there be an 'Else' statement or another piece to code to cancel the process if the user clicks 'Cancel'?  What would that be?

Comment: If the Enter Parameter Value dialog is coming up, it means there is a parameter in the query the form is based on which cannot be resolved.  But that query should not have any parameters in it, as it should contain all the underlying records and the filter should be the mechanism limiting records.  You need to track that down.  As far as the error, you can add error handling to the sub by adding the line On Error Goto xxx.  You can Google VBA error handling for that, but in short, you can make it exit gracefully without ever showing the end user a messagebox on error 2501.